# Steam Client / App Help

Tags: steam

I'm looking for some what I'm sure must be simple help, when I open my Steam App, I can only ever see a list of servers.  There are no options available other than, Change Filters, Quick Refresh, Refresh All and Connect.  I am able to change between various server listings, Internet, Favourites, History, Spectate, Lan and Friends.  But that is all.  I'm trying to activate a game but have no idea how to get to the right screen?

I'm sure that it's a fairly simple click here and there, but it's proving to be beyond me.  Any help, gratefully received.

[image]

Comment: may be add OS\version?

Answer (score 4):

Right click the Steam icon on your taskbar (or equivalent on your operating system) and open settings.

If you don't see settings there, go to your default browser (or the Run prompt on Windows via Win+R) and type in the URL `steam://settings/interface`.

You should now be in your interface settings, where you can select your favorite window, the window to open when you first launch Steam. Within the same menu you can also enable and disable targets to show on the right-click menu I mentioned before.